# How to access asp control inside static method in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net

my Method declared like this :

```
private static void GetHospitaDetails() 
{
    txtAccreditation.Text = "Test"; // Here am not able to assign value to textbox field.
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to access your form controls inside static method

Comment: yes .i am  not able get any controls ID inside static methods.

Comment: You may look at this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1837283.aspx?Access+ASP+web+controls+inside+Static+Methods), for an alternative.

Comment: Try to make function to return a string and then assign it to control. Rather than assigning it into static method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Savedata()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)page.FindControl("TextBox1");

        TextBox TextBox2 = (TextBox)page.FindControl("TextBox2");
    }
}
```

Above method is for finding the control values. The whole point of [WebMethod]s is that they don't run the ASP.Net page lifecycle. This way, they're fast and parallelizable. Your controls don't exist.

Instead, you should use Javascript (better) or an UpdatePanel (worse).